# How to avoid this subquery and create an indexed view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, indexed-view

I work with SQL Server 2008. I have this following table "Forecast".

```
Forecast_ID | Budget_Code | IAM_ID | Forecast | Timestamp
1           | 00-0001     | 24     | 123.41   | '01-01'2010'  
2           | 00-0001     | 10     | 111.41   | '02-02'2010' //Is Last
3           | 00-0001     | 44     | 457.10   | '02-02'2010' //Is Last
4           | 00-0002     | 258    | 20       | '01-05'2011' //Is Last
5           | 00-0003     | 3      | 215      | '11-12'2013' //Is Last
6           | 00-0003     | 31     | 85.2     | '10-01'2010' 
7           | 00-0003     | 2      | 15       | '10-01'2010'
```

I tried to create an indexed view with the lasts "Forecasts" per Budget_Code, i. e. the forecasts with the highest timestamp (one or more rows per Budget_Code).

So I did the following query :

```
CREATE VIEW LastForecasts
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT Forecast_ID, Budget_Code, IAM_ID, Forecast
    FROM dbo.[Plan] p1
    WHERE Timestamp = (
           SELECT MAX(Timestamp) 
           FROM dbo.[Plan] p2 
           WHERE p1.Budget_Code = p2.Budget_Code)
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_V1 
    ON LastForecasts (Forecast_ID);
GO
```

But I have the following error :

***Cannot create index on view "OperationPlanDB.dbo.LastForecasts" because it contains one or more subqueries. Consider changing the view to use only joins instead of subqueries. Alternatively, consider not indexing this view.***

How can I avoid this subquery and index my view with the lasts forecasts ?

Comment: maybe i've missed something but is there any reason why you cant index the Timestamp column (desc or asc, it shouldn't matter) and cover the others (Forecast_ID, Budget_Code, IAM_ID, Forecast), then do a `TOP WITH TIES` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @g2server I don't think `TOP WITH TIES` can work (but I'm not very familiar with it) because I can have one to many rows for each timestamp (see budget code 00-0001 in my example)

Comment: ok I see, I missed the grouping. in that case I think medhi's approach will work (but change to RANK() and try an index on Timestamp, replacing the indexed view with the query - if index is set up correctly performance should be similar).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sub query in your indexed view. I suggest that use following query with better performance instead of your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Forecast_ID, 
            Budget_Code, 
            Forecast,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Budet_Code ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) row
    FROM dbo.[Plan] p1
    )z
WHERE Z.row=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I forgot to say that I can have multiple forecasts with the same timestamp and I need to get all of them if the timestamp is the last for this Budget_Code. By the way, I add another column in my example

Comment: @g2server Indeed it works with RANK() but I still can't use it in indexed view :/ Error : "Cannot create index on view "dbo.LastForecasts" because it contains a ranking or aggregate window function."

Comment: This wouldn't work in an indexed view, would it? Derived tables (`z`) are not supported.